adding SSR to my Angular project does not automatically create app.config.server.ts
I downloaded demo code from an Angular tutorial and decided I wanted to convert it to SSR. I did this exactly what the Angular SSR Docs says. I did the following

npm install to install all the node_modules
ng add @angular/ssr

Here is the expected directory structure from Angular's docs
my-app
|-- server.ts                       # application server
└── src
    |-- app
    |   └── app.config.server.ts    # server application configuration
    └── main.server.ts              # main server application bootstrapping


However, I am missing app.config.server.ts and I think that's why when I open my source code, I only get app-root. If you have an idea why the config is not showing up, then that would be great.

What version of Angular are you using? Can you share a link to the demo code?
